# Users are not able to access the desktop view on the Mobile Devices/ Tablets for the community portal?

Tags: lightning, community, partner-communities, partner-portal, public-calendar

How can I give them Desktop view access to Partner"community" users in Tablet/Mobile devices Browsers. ex: need to show entire calender access in home page like desktop view and need to show opportunity list view in drop down. please check below images.

[image]

Comment: please check this link it will be help for you: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187858&type=1

Comment: Enable Salesforce for Mobile Web" is unchecked. still not showing desktop view